# how to remove weird lines on the spinner

Tags: html, css, vmware-clarity

[image]

I am unable to figure out the reason for the lines appearing on the spinner. what css changes should I have to do in order to remove those lines?

I am using clarity ui framework for the spinner.

```
<img src="asyncImag|async" class="spinner spinner-lg full-media-image-shadow">
```

Comment: Please provide the CSS you are using to create the spinner, we cannot help you if we can't see the code

Comment: I have updated the qstn. I am using Clarity ui framework for the spinner

Comment: Can you add your css you only updated the HTML

Comment: Kind of hard to reproduce.  What is src="asyncImag|async" for ?  An example with Fiddle might helpful in this case.

Comment: @sscotti Not sure, but in the docs its never in an image tag. https://clarity.design/documentation/spinners

Comment: Maybe because of -shadow. just for testing remove full-media-image-shadow class and check.

Comment: I just tried the code on my local machine. It is not showing those lines. Are you sure this is all the code? This may be because of parent div or any other class

Answer (score 1):

Try that then.  Put it in a span.  Always helps to read the documentation.  Not sure that will solve your issue, but seems to work in Fiddle.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clarity-ui/0.10.28/clarity-ui.min.css" integrity="sha256-02co5CslX9xVo7lEtk1q9KPFqZoZo4Jvcb+XeQmQb+Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<span  class="spinner spinner-lg full-media-image-shadow"></span>
```